# how can i disable actions in global search in laravel nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

in laravel nova there is a filed you can override on any resource 
`public static $globallySearchable = false;` to disable searching for that resource, i want to disable actions in global search of nova [a screenshot action results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex9Jc.png) 
i already disabled all resources in global search but still it returns some actions from where those actions are coming ? and how can i get rid of them ?

i already have looked for any available methods to override in **novaServiceProvider** but didn't get any result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Nova had a small not issue bug, they include a resource to brings action logs from the database. This file it's located on the Nova source folder in ./nova/src/Actions/ActionResource.php. To avoid this behavior, just add this line to the class:

```
class ActionResource extends Resource
{
    //This is the line to add
    public static $globallySearchable = false;
```

This going to stop showing the resource results on the Global Search.

I got the answer from [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/nova/how-can-i-disable-actions-in-global-search-in-laravel-nova)

Answer (score 0):

You will lose your changes after nova update if you use the provided solution.

Please check better one at

https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/2635#issuecomment-642219333